# Conflict between @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers and @openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades for ethers version

Tags: npm, upgrade, hardhat, openzeppelin, version-conflict-engine-exception

[image: Error while installing @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers conflicting ethers versions]

Error was shown while downloading the package, I tried updating all the packages using
`npm update` 
to their latest verions. It didn't helped.
I also tried force installation that also didn't work.

Do I need to change the versions to a compatable version and if so what is version that is currently compatible.